# How do I make gVim detect a certain font?

Tags: fonts, gvim

I recently installed a font named "Hermit", and it is detected by my computer as you can see here:-
[image]However, when I open gVim and try to change my font it isn't an option in the font selector, as you can see here

[image: here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peJRY.png).

Answer (score 0):

GVim only lists fonts which describe themselves as being monospaced.

I suspect you are using an older version of Hermit which failed to do this correctly.  The changelog for 2.0 mentions:

> Marked as monospaced (isFixedPitch).

[Download version 2.0](https://pcaro.es/d/otf-hermit-2.0.tar.gz) directly from its [creator's website](https://pcaro.es/p/hermit/), to ensure you have the latest version.